# Excel: is it possible to extract a superscript letter from a word?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, formatting

I'm wondering if these is a way of using a formula to find a superscript letter, rather than just the last letter of a word.

I have lots of tabs, with nearly matching tables on each one showing up to 34 categories. These categories can have footnotes attached to them. To show tha a footnote is attached a '*superscript*' letter is added just after the category name (nothing new there).

Unfortunatley these footnotes have become out of control and the people who managed this file before me just stop putting them in order. So I am therefore going to change the system. Rather than a footnote I'm just using an asterix next to the category, and the category name will be used below in the footnotes - makes more sense and is easier to manage!

I'm now thinking of the quickest way to manage this massive task and keeping integrity with the footnotes. I'm wondering if these is a way of using a formula to find a superscript letter, rather than just the last letter.

If I could do this then I could use another one to extract the category name - up until the superscript letter. I could then more easily cut & paste footnote letters with category names.

Any ideas or suggestions gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Are you willing to use VBA macros ?
If yes, there is a "Font.Superscript" function you could test.

Comment: I'm certainly open to ideas, but VBA is not something I meddle with very much - not without help from others from this forum anyway.

Comment: @Mike: This is not a forum but a Q&A site. The only way to approach this is by scripting, since you are asking something very specific. Visual Basic is no rocket science, some simple Googling will get you there... :)